# vue component compiling fine but not showing up or registering

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

On laravel environment - I have a vuejs component that I'm trying to incorporate. However, for some reason the component is not showing up on the page.

In vue devtools, the component isn't there either. There aren't any errors in the console and I can't find any issues in the vue template, blade template, or the object that the component is using either. When I look at the compiled app.js file, the vue component code is there.

Anyone have any thoughts as to what may be happening?

vue component:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="bold" for="refund_amount">Amount to Refund</label>
            <div class="form-group">
                <i class="fa fa-usd"></i>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="refund_amount" placeholder="Enter amount in format of 0.00" v-model="invoice.refund_amount" /> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="bold" for="refund_reason">Reason/Notes for Refund</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="refund_reason" rows="3" v-model="invoice.refund_reason" placeholder="Please provide some information as to why you are processing the refund."></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @click="initiateRefund()">Initiate Refund</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import { eventBus } from '../../app';

    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                invoice: this.data[0],
                success: null
            }
        },
        props: ['data'],
        methods: {
            initiateRefund() {
                axios.post('/admin/invoice/' + this.invoice.id + '/refund', { invoice: this.invoice })
                    .then(response => {
                        this.success = true;
                        eventBus.$emit('invoiceUpdated', response.data.date);
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            this.success = null;
                        }, 2000);
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        alert(error);
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

loading the component on the blade template:

```
<admin-refund :data="{{ $vue_data }}"></admin-refund>
```

full blade template:

```
@section('content')
<!-- Start main-content -->
<div id="app" class="main-content">
    <section id="middle">

        <!-- page title -->
        <header id="page-header">
        </header>
        <!-- /page title -->

        <div id="content" class="padding-20">
            <div id="invoice" class="panel panel-default">
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="invoice-buttons">
            </div>

            @if($invoice->refunded == 0)
            <!-- Panel -->
            <div id="refund" class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <span class="title elipsis">
                        <strong>Process Refund</strong> <!-- panel title -->
                    </span>
                    <!-- right options -->
                    <ul class="options pull-right list-inline">
                        <li><a href="#" class="opt panel_colapse" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Colapse" data-placement="bottom"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="opt panel_fullscreen hidden-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Fullscreen" data-placement="bottom"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="opt panel_close" data-confirm-title="Confirm" data-confirm-message="Are you sure you want to remove this panel?"
                                data-toggle="tooltip" title="Close" data-placement="bottom"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /right options -->
                </div>
                <!-- panel content -->
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <?php var_dump($vue_data); ?>
                     <?php var_dump($vue_data[0]); ?>

                    <admin-refund :data="{{ $vue_data }}"></admin-refund>


                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /Panel -->
            @endif

        </div>
    </section>
</div>
@endsection
```

when I var_dump($vue_data):

```
/storage/framework/views/0b20617b5b1397ecd57c6a3a53c931039f8279e6.php:40:
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[391]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[380]
          public 'id' => int 341
          public 'event_id' => int 1002
          public 'user_id' => int 1
          public 'amount' => string '26' (length=2)
          public 'addons' => string '[]' (length=2)
          public 'customer_id' => string 'cus_C07' (length=18)
          public 'charge_id' => string 'ch_1Bc6v' (length=27)
          public 'subscription_id' => null
          public 'receipt_email' => string 'test@test.com' (length=18)
          public 'refunded' => int 0
          public 'refund_amount' => string '0.00' (length=4)
          public 'refund_reason' => null
          public 'refunded_at' => null
          public 'created_at' => string '2017-12-23 01:53:59' (length=19)
          public 'updated_at' => string '2017-12-26 01:35:14' (length=19)
```

part of the app.js file

```
require('./bootstrap');

// Vue
window.Vue = require('vue');

import axios from 'axios';

import AdminRefund from "./components/admin/AdminRefund.vue";

export const userBus = new Vue();
export const stripeBus = new Vue();
export const eventBus = new Vue();

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        adminRefund: AdminRefund
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me.  Any chance you could create a fiddle with the VueJS bits that you can use to reproduce the issue?  Just a silly question perhaps, but you didn't forget to recompile your javascript after adding the adminRefund component?

Comment: yup, been running 'npm run watch-poll' the whole time. appears the fiddle works?

https://jsfiddle.net/oww94tmc/ @DavidHeremans

Comment: Oh - I never really provide data to my components in blade, but shouldn’t you do data=“{{$vue_data}}” without the semicolon?  I would expect some error in console though...

Comment: Tried that but no difference - no error on console or during compiling. Usually I've been using the semicolon. Vue devtools isn't even recognizing anything. It's saying "Vue.js not detected". So for whatever reason, the vue isn't loading at all. However, my vue components are working on other pages fine. @DavidHeremans

Comment: In that case - are you even sure that for this particular blade, you are including the VueJS library?  If it says Vue.js not detected, it may just be because it wasn't loaded properly?

Comment: thank you!! no idea how I missed that.. forgot to add the script line

Comment: You’re welcome :-)